# Using result of query to another query with IN()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to using result of query to another query with IN():

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $id .= $value['id'];}

$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM table where id IN($id)';
```

but the $id must be in 'id1, id2, id3' format. With `$id .= $value['quiz_id'].' , ';`
there is one comma after last id. How can I convert $id value to `'id1, id2, id3'`.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $idArr[] = $value['id']
}

$idStr = implode(',', $idArr);

$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM table where id IN($idStr)';
```

This will give you a comma separated string of ids that you can use in your IN() query.

Hope that helps

Comment: @TheNone I would integrate the extra lines of code that @Pekka gave in his example. This will stop any errors in the case that no ids are returned. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use an array:

```
$ids = array(); 
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
 $ids[] = $value['id'];}

if (count($ids) > 0)   // to avoid mySQL error on empty array
 {
   $ids_string = implode(",", $ids);
   $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM table where id IN($ids_string)'; 
 }
```